# Fill a list with data getting from the SharePreferences

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I would please need your help.
I would like to fill a spinner with data from another class. 
When I click on the button btn_add, it adds data into my database. At the same time I store the "String-quality" into the sharedPreferences. The List I would like to fill is in the MainActivity-class and the button into the AddActivity-class.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;
 ::::

 public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_activity);

 btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(AddActivity.this, "Plant.sqlite", null, 1);
                    sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                            edt_quality.getText().toString().trim(),
                            edt_name.getText().toString().trim()
                    );
                    //////////////////SharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TheQualities", 0);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                    editor.putString("quality", edt_quality.getText().toString().trim());
                    editor.apply();

                    //reset
                    resetFields(),
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

In the following class, I would like to fill my list. 
1. problem: After sending data into my database, I have to restart the program before the quality appears into my list. I would like to update my list at the same time I send data into my database. 
2. problem: The previous quality is always replace by the new one, I would like to fill the list and to maintain the eldest quality in the list.

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  ::::

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {


 Spinner spinner;

 public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "item.sqlite", null, 1);

    // Get reference of widgets from XML layout
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerX);

    // Initializing an ArrayAdapter
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fillList()) {
    };                                                                                               spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    }
};

//RETRIEVING PREFERENCES
public String getQuality() {
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("TheQualities", 0);
return prefs.getString("quality", "choice");
}

public List<String> fillList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if(!list.contains(getQuality())) {
        list.add(getQuality());
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

NB: there is no error while running the app.
Please does someone have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: your previous quality is being replaced by the new one, because you are saving the single value in preferences and getting the single value from preferences. instead of that you should save some list inside the preference or you should change the code where you are getting the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quickly put together example as per the suggestion only using tables. That will also select the items according to the selected category.

Note this adds, for the sake of demonstration, 1 initial category (My First Category) and 1 item,that uses the My First Category. The item being named My First Item.

When listed the item's Category is also displayed.

It does not facilitate adding items. However, it does facilitate adding categories (noting that selecting an added from the spinner, will show nothing in the list, but re-selecting My First category will then list the item).

**SQLiteHelper.java**

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydatabase";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_ITEM = "item";
    public static final String TABLE_CATEGORY = "category";

    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_NAME = "itemname";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_CATEGORYREF = "category_reference";

    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME = "category";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_item_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEM + "(" +
                COLUMN_ITEM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_ITEM_CATEGORYREF + " INTEGER" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_item_table);

        String crt_category_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORY + "(" +
                COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_category_table);
        mDB = db;
        // ADD AN INITIAL CATEGORY AND THEN AN ITEM USING THAT CATEGORY
        addCateory("My FIRST CATEGORY");
        addItem("My First Item",1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addCateory(String category) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME,category);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY,null,cv);
    }

    public long addItem(String name, long category_reference) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_ITEM_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_ITEM_CATEGORYREF,category_reference);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_ITEM,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllCategories() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_CATEGORY,null,null,null,null,null, COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + " ASC");
    }

    public Cursor getAllItemsWithCategoryName(long category_id) {
        String table = TABLE_ITEM +
                " JOIN " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " ON " + TABLE_ITEM + "." + COLUMN_ITEM_CATEGORYREF + " = " + TABLE_CATEGORY + "." + COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID;
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                TABLE_ITEM + "." + COLUMN_ITEM_ID,
                COLUMN_ITEM_NAME,
                COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME
        };
        String whereclause;
        String[] whereargs;
        if (category_id < 1) {
            whereclause = null;
            whereargs = null;
        } else {
            whereclause = COLUMN_ITEM_CATEGORYREF + "=?";
            whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(category_id)};
        }
        return mDB.query(table,columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,COLUMN_ITEM_NAME + " ASC");
    }
}
```

- Note the QUERY for the items in the **`getAllItemsWithCategoryName`** method is effectively `SELECT item._id, itemname, category FROM item JOIN category ON item._id = category._id WHERE category_reference = ? ORDER BY itemname ASC`

  - ? will be the selected category id (category._id)
  - Note if the selected category id is 0, then the WHERE clause is omitted.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Define class variables/objects
    Spinner mCategorySpinner;
    long mCurrentSelectedcategory = 0;
    ListView mItemList;
    Button btn_add;
    Cursor mCategories, mItems;
    SQLiteHelper mDBHlpr;

    CursorAdapter mCategorySpinnerAdapter;
    CursorAdapter mItemListViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         * Added button to initiate AddActivity
         */
        btn_add = this.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mCategorySpinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinnerX);
        mItemList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.item_listview);
        mDBHlpr = new SQLiteHelper(this);
        setupOrRefreshUI();

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupOrRefreshUI() {

        //Category Spinner
        mCategories = mDBHlpr.getAllCategories();
        if (mCategorySpinnerAdapter == null) {
            mCategorySpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    mCategories,
                    new String[]{
                            SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME
                    },
                    new int[]{
                            android.R.id.text1
                    },
                    0
            );
            ((SimpleCursorAdapter) mCategorySpinnerAdapter).setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mCategorySpinner.setAdapter(mCategorySpinnerAdapter);
            mCategorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    mCurrentSelectedcategory = l;
                    setupOrRefreshUI();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            mCategorySpinnerAdapter.swapCursor(mCategories);
        }

        //Item ListView
        mItems = mDBHlpr.getAllItemsWithCategoryName(mCurrentSelectedcategory);
        if (mItemListViewAdapter == null) {
            mItemListViewAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mItems,
                    new String[]{
                            SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME,
                            SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME
                    },
                    new int[]{
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            android.R.id.text2
                    },
                    0
            );
            mItemList.setAdapter(mItemListViewAdapter);
            mItemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< handle clicking an item here
                }
            });
        } else {
            mItemListViewAdapter.swapCursor(mItems);
        }
    }

    /**
     * ADDED as this is called when activity is resumed, so rebuild the Spinner's list
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setupOrRefreshUI();
    }
}
```

**AddActivity.java**

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edt_quality;
    Button btn_add, btn_done;
    SQLiteHelper mDBHlpr;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        edt_quality = this.findViewById(R.id.edt_quality);
        btn_add = this.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        btn_done = this.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        mDBHlpr = new SQLiteHelper(this);


        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newcategory = edt_quality.getText().toString();
                if (newcategory.length() > 0) {
                    mDBHlpr.addCateory(newcategory);
                }
            }
        });

        btn_done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD NEW CATEGORY"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerX"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/item_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_add.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_quality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAVE CATEGORY"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DONE ADDING CATEGORIES"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE** The above is a working example, provided solely as a demonstration of how you could solve the numerous issues.

Comment: Thank you @Mike T for that example.

Answer (score 0):

The Spinner will not magically refresh assuming that your flow is that you go to the AddActivity from the MainActivity, add the quality and then return.

If that is the case you need to refresh the Spinner's source and then tell the adapter that the data has changed. You do the latter using the Adapter's **notifyDatasetChanged** method.

Using List is very limited for List's (Spinner's, Listviews) that change. ArrayList is more adaptable.

Assuming the above, then the following is a working example based upon your code.

- Note database access code has been commented out.
- To simulate invoking the AddActivity a button has been added to MainActivity.
- To simulate returnin/finishing

### Code

#### AddActivity (basically button added for return)

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edt_quality;
    Button btn_add, btn_done;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_activity);
        edt_quality = this.findViewById(R.id.edt_quality);
        btn_add = this.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        btn_done = this.findViewById(R.id.done_button);


        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    /*
                }
                    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(AddActivity.this, "Plant.sqlite", null, 1);
                    sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                            edt_quality.getText().toString().trim(),
                            edt_name.getText().toString().trim()
                    );
                    */
                    //////////////////SharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TheQualities", 0);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                    editor.putString("quality", edt_quality.getText().toString().trim());
                    editor.apply();

                    //reset
                    //resetFields()
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity (see comments)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Define class variables/objects
    Spinner spinner;
    Button btn_add;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mSpinnerArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> mFillList; //<<<<<<<<<< changed from List<String>

    //public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         * Added button to initiate AddActivity
         */
        btn_add = this.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "item.sqlite", null, 1);

        // Get reference of widgets from XML layout
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerX);
        fillList(); //<<<<<<<<<< Fill the list for the spinner (will initially be empty)
        // Initializing an ArrayAdapter
        mSpinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mFillList) {
        };
        mSpinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerArrayAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * ADDED as this is called when activity is resumed, so rebuild the Spinner's list
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fillList();
    }

    public String getQuality() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("TheQualities", 0);
        return prefs.getString("quality", "choice");
    }

    /**
     * Changed to do a little more depending upon status of the list and adapter
     */
    public void fillList() {
        // Initialise arraylist if not already initalised
        if (mFillList == null) {
            mFillList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        // clear all elements from the arraylist
        mFillList.clear();
        // add the element (only ever 1)
        if(!mFillList.contains(getQuality())) {
            mFillList.add(getQuality());
        }
        // If the Adapter has been initialised then notify that the data has changed
        if (mSpinnerArrayAdapter != null) {
            mSpinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

#### When App starts (very first time after install)

[image]

- Nothing in Spinner.

#### Add button is clicked on MainActivity

[image]

- **Very Good** is then entered in the EditText, **ADD** is clicked and then **DONE** is clicked :-

#### Main Activity is resumed

[image]

- and as you can see **Very Good** can now be selected in the Spinner.
- **Note as it stands there will only ever be 1 choice, you would be better off obtaining the list from the database.**

Comment: Thank you @Mike T for your answer. Why does the ArrayList<String> will only have one choice, even though I add many data in it via the AddActivity ? **Note as it stands there will only ever be 1 choice, you would be better off obtaining the list from the database.** Why this ? And why all elements of the List disappear, when I restart the App ?

Comment: These are all questions that need to be asked as other questions. Did the answer allow you to get data, albeit only 1, from shared preferences? If so mark the question as answered. Then ask other questions and include the relevant code.

Comment: Ok @Mike T. , Thanks for your disponibility

Comment: @Kel the additional answer (not to be ticked) may be of assistance.